# Making a flexible file path reader for discord.js using fs?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

[The error from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNlWJ.jpg)

I’ve been working for a while on making commands for my discord.js bot, but now I am starting to categorize them. My commands are currently being put into a collector for a new discord collection (named client.{commandType}commands). I want to make “{commandType}” to be changed out for the value “i” in the following code. Anyone know how to do this?

```
folder.forEach(i => {
  fs.readdir(`/home/runner/commands/${i}`, (err, file) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    let jsfile = file.filter(f => f.split(`.`).pop() === `js`);

    jsfile.forEach((f,e) => {
      let props = require(`/home/runner/commands/${i}/${f}`);

      client.commandPermissions.set(props.help.name, props.help.permissionLevel);

      console.log(`${props.help.name}: ${props.help.permissionLevel}`);

      client.{commandType}command.set(props.help.name, props);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    });

  });

});
```

So how do I fix that?

Edit: Just so I am clear, I am essentially trying to do this: `client. + i + commands.set(props.help.name, props);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use:

```
client[i + 'command'].set(props.help.name, props);
```

Unlike many other languages, JavaScript has no difference between an object and a dictionary/hashmap. You are able to use either notation (`obj.property` or `obj['property']`) to access a property of an object. The main difference between them is that `obj.property` looks better, but in `obj['property']`, `'property'` can be a normal string, a variable, or some other expression.

Comment: Hate to say it, but it didnt work. Gave me an error saying unexpected token ‘[’

Comment: @Silveradoz did you do `client.[i + 'command']` or `client[i + 'command']`? The latter is the correct syntax.

Comment: I used both. Neither one worked sadly.
Also, I’ll add a photo of the error.

Comment: @Silveradoz I just noticed, is it `command` or `commands`? You use both in your question, but I assume only one is correct.

Comment: That would be it (Hopefully)! I did use commands. I’ll test it and let you know. 
> Nope. Says the same error as shown in the top of the post... hmm... 
Also, am I properly tagging you? With your username I am not entirely sure...

Comment: @Silveradoz I'm not sure what to problem is, then. As far as I am aware, `obj.property` and `obj['property']` are exactly identical. Perhaps try debugging it by verifying what properties exist on `client`, and printing what properties you're trying to access. In regards to tagging, it doesn't matter. I get a notification any time anyone comments on any of my posts.

Comment: Found it! If I use 

        client[`${i}commands`].set(props.help.name, props);

it works